# Can you have an embedded browser in Gamemaker:Studio

Tags: browser-based-games, game-maker, browser

I am trying to make a sort of browser in gamemaker and I wanted to know how to embed a browser within a game. **Are there any extensions I need to download?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows projects you can use https://marketplace.yoyogames.com/assets/683/web-browser